# How to fetch the folder or files names from an absolute path in a tree View using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

itemlist.java:::

```
public class itemlist {

public TreeItem<File> createNode(final File f) {
return new TreeItem<File>(f) {
private boolean isLeaf;
private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;`

@Override
public ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> getChildren() {
  if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
    isFirstTimeChildren = false;
    super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(this));
  }
  return super.getChildren();
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf() {
  if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
    isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
    File f = (File) getValue();
    isLeaf = f.isFile();
  }
  return isLeaf;
}

private ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> buildChildren(
    TreeItem<File> TreeItem) {
  File f = TreeItem.getValue();
  if (f == null) {
    return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
  }
  if (f.isFile()) {
    return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
  }
  File[] files = f.listFiles();
 // String allfiles= files.toString();
  //allfiles.

  if (files != null) {
    ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> children = FXCollections
        .observableArrayList();
    for (File childFile : files) {
      children.add(createNode(childFile));
    }
    return children;
  }
  return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
}
```

*controller.java::::*

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    itemlist obj=new itemlist();
    TreeItem<File> rt =obj.createNode(new File("c:\\"));
    fileView.setRoot(rt);`
```

So this gives me an output like
`C:\\programfiles ->C:\\programfiles\java ->C:\\programfiles\python`
All I want is to remove these absolute path & just game the file/folder name. I understand using getName would help that but how do I implement getName() in my code?

Comment: you need a custom cell ... and stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: can you please tell me more about custom cell? I'm new to javafx ,so I dont have wide knowledge about what custom cell is

Comment: _tell me more about custom cell_ work through a tutorial on how to use TreeView .. instead of simply copying code, like from the api doc ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change generic type from File to String and use only the file name:

```java
    class ItemList {
    
        public TreeItem<String> createNode(final File f) {
            return new TreeItem<String>(f.getName()) {
                private boolean isLeaf;
                private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
                private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;
    
                @Override
                public ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> getChildren() {
                    if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
                        isFirstTimeChildren = false;
                        super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(f));
                    }
                    return super.getChildren();
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean isLeaf() {
                    if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
                        isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
                        isLeaf = f.isFile();
                    }
                    return isLeaf;
                }
    
                private ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> buildChildren(
                        File f) {
    
                    if (f == null) {
                        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
                    }
                    if (f.isFile()) {
                        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
                    }
                    File[] files = f.listFiles();
                    
                    if (files != null) {
                        ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> children = FXCollections
                                .observableArrayList();
                        for (File childFile : files) {
                            children.add(createNode(childFile));
                        }
                        return children;
                    }
                    return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

```java
    ItemList obj = new ItemList();
    TreeItem<String> rt = obj.createNode(new File("/"));
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rt);
```

Comment: I tried replacing Files to String from the above piece of code you shared,but when I am trying to run the file ,the tree view is now empty. No root nodes or any childrens getting printed on treeview

Comment: what worked for me is replacing the line "new TreeView<>(rt)" with "treeView.setRoot(rt)"

Comment: possible but a bad piece of code: you are building the tree (== data structure) around its visual requirements (== view). On the way, you are loosing all inherent content (like all item properties related to its fileness and the structural relation between the files). What if you need to react to modifications of the underlying file system? What if you want to show other properties than the name? Repeating my comment to the question: a _TreeCell_ is the collaborator that is responsible for customizing the view, nothing else.

Comment: I agree in general. I posted simple solution for this particular case.